# iOS understanding accelerometer data of iphone in free fall

Tags: iphone, ios, signal-processing, physics, accelerometer

[image: Raw accelerometer data including gravity][image: Processed accelerometer data not including gravity]Why is it that when i drop my phone from about 4 feet onto a pillow, and plot the magnitude of the user acceleration i get peak values of 1.5g then 1g then 2.5g then 1g then 2.5g then 0g in a 1 second time frame in free fall with 10 samples. Ideally it should be accelerating at a constant rate downwards due to gravity minus the air resistance, so why does the acceleration go up and down while in free fall? What is causing this noise?

Comment: Note that the time required to fall 4 feet is about 1/2 second.  So only 5 of your 10 samples apply to the actual fall.

Comment: One question I have is how you calculated the value from x,y,z axis reading. Is it simply square root of x, y, z reading?

Comment: @barley yes: sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

Comment: Are you sure it is from raw values of accelerometer? It looks like after high-pass filtering (filtering out DC component). I have experience with iPhone accelerometer (although not with the latest iOS), but it showed close to 1G when resting.

Comment: @barley this is not the raw data, this is the user acceleration only (i.e. raw acceleration minus the gravity component).

Comment: In that case, I probably go with @johnluttig's answer. The movement on collision can be very complex which you can only hypothesize, but it feels quite natural to imagine bouncing effect even on the pillow. Probably not relevant with this specific data, but a tip you may want to know : Not officially stated, but it is a well known observation that [iPhone accelerometer value is cut off around +-2.3G](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4822-maximum-accelerometer-reading.html) It is about raw reading from each axis, but user acceleration will be affected as well of course.

Comment: "raw acceleration minus the gravity component" -- how are you subtracting out gravity??

Comment: Actually, the only real oddity of the bottom graph is the spike up to 1.5 initially.  And that could easily be due to the response curve of the accelerometer -- likely there's some filtering to attempt to "peak" it's "high-frequency" response, and that, combined with sampling artifacts, causes the peak.  Net/net is that a single 100ms measurement is probably not too trustworthy in terms of accuracy -- you need to average over 2-3 to get reasonable results.  (The top graph is indecipherable.)

Comment: @HotLicks I finally figured out. The poster should be using [CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration in iOS SDK](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMDeviceMotion#userAcceleration). I guess high-pass filter is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important concept to understand before reading my post is that **acceleration relative to the ground** (*not* accelerometer reading) due to gravity will always be 1.0g. However, this acceleration can be diminished/enhanced by external factors such as air resistance, stopping force, applied force, etc.

It is important to recognize the difference between actual acceleration and the accelerometer reading before noticing the variation between my answer and the others. I have answered your question in terms of acceleration because your graph does not seem to reflect raw accelerometer readings, but rather acceleration relative to the ground. To clarify:

- Accelerometer value = abs(acceleration WRT ground - 1g)

Therefore:

- When acceleration is 0g (object is at rest), the accelerometer reads 1g.
- When acceleration is 1g (object is in free fall), the accelerometer reads 0g.

Here is a probable situation for each acceleration WRT ground that you posted:

1.5g: When dropping the iPhone, you probably accidentally applied a small force of ~0.5g, causing an acceleration of 1.5g (1.0g due to gravity + 0.5g applied).

1.0g: Once it is in actual free fall, it reads ~1.0g (acceleration due to gravity). This is the acceleration it should hypothetically be reading the entire time it is in free fall, neglecting air resistance.

2.5g: When it hits the pillow, it has an upwards acceleration of ~2.5g because it is stopping after having gained speed from gravity.

0.0g: After it has stopped, it has 0.0g of acceleration because it isn't accelerating. Acceleration due to gravity has been neutralized by the normal forced exerted by pillow.

Comment: Makes sense, but after 2.5g it goes back to 1g then 2.5g again then back to 0g. How do you make sense of that?

Comment: Your comment about 1.0g and 0.0g is not correct. It is 1G When accelerometer is sitting, and 0G when free falling. @hot-licks states it correctly in his answer.

Comment: @barley My answer is in terms of acceleration, not accelerometer readings. I just edited my answer to clarify the difference between the two.

Comment: @gambit14 Probably hits the pillow, then bounces back up, then falls back down on the pillow and comes to rest.

Comment: @johnluttig I posted the raw data above as well, it makes sense. So i'm guessing the spikes from 3s to 5s is due to the small force applied by me when i dropped the phone, from 5s to about 7.5s its in free fall (1g) then the 2g spike at 8s is due to hitting the pillow?

Comment: +1 for an imperfect answer, but well thought out and quite close.

Comment: @gambit14 That's my best guess. +1 for good question and followup.

Answer (score 3):

The accelerometer is measuring force with respect to the iPhone case.  When sitting still on the table, gravity is forcing the accelerometer chip into the bottom of the iPhone case with a force of 1G.  When in free fall, both the accelerometer chip and the iPhone case will undergo the same downward force due to gravity of 1G.  But then since, in free fall, both the chip and the case will be accelerating downward at the identical rate, there is no force of the chip against the iPhone case, they'll both be falling together, so you get a reading very close to zero G.

So 1 G while you hold it still up in the air.  0 Gs in free fall.  Many G's during the deepest contact part of the bounce.  0 Gs during the up in the air part of the bounce rebound.  Many G's during the next contact with the pillow, etc.  Back to 1 G when sitting still on the pillow.

This is a slight simplification, as the measurement is actually of one part of the chip against another, but the argument still works, but more on a nano-scale.

Answer (score 3):

Einstein discovered something obvious (but hidden in plain sight). That is: what we experience as gravity is actually acceleration. When on the ground, and not moving, we are actually accelerating upward at 1G (one earth gravity). So the earth is actually expanding outward from the center.

Now a funny thing happens with matter (or a large mass like the Earth): space and time around the mass actually collapses at the exact same rate as the expansion. That's why clocks run faster when you move away from the center of the earth or off the Earth's surface. This has been verified in countless experiments and must be taken into consideration in order for GPS satellites to function correctly (for example).

Now a true accelerometer will always measure 1G on the ground. When you released it, the accelerometer goes into "free fall" which means it is now moving at a constant velocity (not accelerating)and thus reads: 0G. Instead of the accelerometer accelerating, the ground accelerates up to meet the falling object because the ground has accelerated upward during the one second of weightless free-fall experienced by the accelerometer. The instantaneous acceleration when striking the pillow is therefore much higher than 1G. Using the pillow as a spring to gently introduce the new instantaneous velocity of the earth to the momentarily weightless accelerometer was a good idea.

Instantaneous acceleration to any instrument is very destructive... and iPhones very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Is the phone spinning? Air resistance will vary depending on the "profile" presented in the direction of acceleration (down), which means acceleration will vary. The 0g sample is either a spot where the location of the sensor in the phone happened to be rotating/spinning downwards at the same rate as gravity, and/or the phone hit terminal velocity (not likely on a 4' fall).

Comment: "or the phone hit terminal velocity" You never know, he could have thrown it out of a plane, through his roof, and onto a pillow.

Comment: OP says it's a 4 foot drop. phones aren't exactly a piece of paper or a feather, so terminal velocity in 4 feet is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when the phone is sitting on the table, the acceleration is 1G.  In a free-fall the acceleration is 0G.  I've never played with the iPhone accelerometer to know whether the support logic "fakes" 0G when stationary and "fakes" 1G when falling, but if it does it would inevitably be imperfect.

What you should see (from an un-fudged accelerometer) in a free-fall is starting at 1G, decreasing rapidly to 0G while falling, increasing rapidly to several Gs when it hits the "ground", then returning to 1G after rebounding stops, perhaps after several cycles up and down.

Comment: Check out the graph i posted. And i dont get why it would be 0g during free fall?

Comment: @johnluttig -- Gravity.  And Einstein.

Comment: Because gravity from the earth is always existent. We are always pulled by gravity to the ground.

Comment: @gambit14 -- The phone is apparently "faking" 0G when at rest.  The graph looks about like what I'd expect for this -- start at zero, hit about 1.5 while the phone figures out that it's falling, level off near 1, then peak above 2.5 on impact.  The rest is rebound.  The only anomaly is the early peak at 1.5, but if the phone is tumbling at all (or even if not) the code will have trouble doing it's fakery and such anomalies are likely.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you're just talking about the accelerometer readings in your answer and I'm talking about actual acceleration of the object, which is what his graph is displaying.

Comment: @johnluttig I am apparently being a smart-ass :), but "actual acceleration" also depends whether it is relative to you or to the center of earth. I expect iPhone accelerometer to output relative acceleration "to the center of earth", and thereby, it should show 1G at rest and 0G when free-falling. Otherwise, I think there should be some calculation (filtering) involved in the poster's output...

Comment: @barley Gotcha. I just answered based on the OP's values that he provided, which suggested that acceleration is being measured relative to the ground. By "actual acceleration", I meant relative to the ground. Oops, should have clarified. I usually don't think about acceleration relative to the center of earth.

Comment: Relative to the center of the earth or the surface of the earth doesn't make much difference.  So long as the phone is above the surface of the earth, and not to far above, it will experience 1G when at rest.

Comment: @johnluttig -- I'm talking about what an accelerometer reads.  The graph above is clearly not showing what the actual accelerometer reads, but some sort of "adjusted" data.

Comment: @johnluttig -- And "actual acceleration" is in the eye of the beholder (literally).  With no external reference it's impossible to distinguish acceleration from gravity.  In a sense, gravity is just acceleration through curved space.